# jquery ajax post failing when parameter has more than one word

Tags: jquery

When using jquery ajax to post a parameter to a php page it is fine when the string contains only one word

```
 $.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 dataType: "json",
 data: { query: 'london'},
 url: "/autosuggest.php",
 });
```

but with 2 words space seperated it returns a 400 badly formatted request error

```
 $.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 dataType: "json",
 data: { query: 'london h'},
 url: "/autosuggest.php",
 });
```

Can any one point me in the right direction?

Comment: don't think so I'm not posting to a url with any parameters, the data is being sent as json

Comment: jQuery converts the object to a string and takes care of encoding for you, the issue is most likely serverside, and we can look at the ajax call all day without getting any closer to an answer.

Comment: the php side is fairly simple it makes a curl call

Answer (score 0):

By default `jQuery.ajax` send data with `contentType=application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. This is means, that your parameters added to url, and your url looks like this:

```
/autosuggest.php?query=london h
```

Of course it is invalid url. To pass string with spaces to you php page, you should use `contentType=application/json`:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: { query: 'london h'},
    url: "/autosuggest.php",
});
```

Comment: when I dump the $_POST serverside with that code it is emtpy

Comment: I added contentType with error, it should be 'application/json', check again